My PostgreSql Query returns nothing even though matching data is Present
need your help on what is going wrong in my Query, I am executing a Dynamic Query, This query is meant to display test case results in a tabular format where each row represents a test case and each column represents a different software version (BuildVersion). The MAX(CASE ... END) construct is used to pivot the data so that the ResultStatus for each test case is shown under the corresponding BuildVersion column. Finally I use this Query in Grafana if it returns the expected result
However currently it is not returning anything but runs successfully, I feel there is something missing in this line of code

 ' || string_agg('MAX(CASE WHEN "BuildVersion" = ' || quote_literal('BuildVersion') || ' THEN "ResultStatus" END) AS "' || 'BuildVersion' || '"', ', ') || ' 

which Iam unable to crack please help
Complete Query:
DO $$
DECLARE
    versions text;
    query text;

BEGIN
    -- Get distinct software versions
    SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT '"' || "BuildVersion" || '"', ', ') INTO versions
    FROM public."Builds";
 RAISE NOTICE 'Value: %', Versions;
    -- Create the dynamic query
    query := '

    SELECT
        "TestCaseName",
        ' || string_agg('MAX(CASE WHEN "BuildVersion" = ' || quote_literal('BuildVersion') || ' THEN "ResultStatus" END) AS "' || 'BuildVersion' || '"', ', ') || '
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                b."BuildVersion",
                tcn."TestCaseName",
                r."ResultStatus"
            FROM
                "TestRecords" tr
                JOIN "TestCases" tc ON tr."TestCaseID" = tc."TestCaseID"
                JOIN "Builds" b ON tr."BuildID" = b."BuildID"
                JOIN "TestCaseNames" tcn ON tr."TestCaseID" = tcn."TestCaseNameID"
                JOIN "Result" r ON tr."ResultID" = r."ResultID"
        ) AS subquery
    GROUP BY
        "TestCaseName"
    ORDER BY
        "TestCaseName";';

 
    -- Execute the dynamic query
    EXECUTE query;
END $$;```
 
Current Output Message I get is : NOTICE:  Value: "2203.2.50.280", "2203.2.50.290", "2203.2.50.350", "2403.4.11.27", "2403.4.12.29", "2403.4.12.30", "2403.4.12.31"
DO

Query returned successfully in 561 msec.

Expected Result:      |2203.2.50.280| 2203.2.50.290 | 2203.2.50.350
             Test1    |  pass       |  Fail         |  Pass
             Test2    | fail        |  Pass         |  Pass
             Test3    | pass        |  Pass         |  Pass


I think this is nearly impossible to help you with as stated.  can you print out the sql that is generated? do you have sample data to use as inputs? and lastly you should show expected outputs.

You've put string_agg in the query := part but there is no FROM so there is nothing to aggregate. I think you have that in the wrong place: that concatenation should be in the INTO versions bit as a separate variable.

DO doesn't return anything. Your queries could be fine, when executed inside an anonymous code block you get nothing: returning void. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html

Please use the [edit] button and put that in your question.

Yes I have added the Expected Result in my Question at the end , also I have printed how the Build Version Data looks like

@Randy can you please check I have given the complete Query in Question and also at the end mentioned the expected result too
